# algorithm to search for duplicated information?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to code a program that prompts the user that the information they enter is duplicated. But Dev-C++ keeps telling me 'class Student' has no member named 'p', so I'm guessing there's something wrong with the algorithm or the code, please have a look:

Student.h

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_

#include "Person.h"

class Student: public Person {
    int ent_year;
    string major;
    public:
        Student *next;
        Student ();
        Student (int i_pid, string i_fname, string i_dob, string i_addr, int i_ent_year, string i_major);
        void Show ();

        void Set_ent_year (int i_ent_year);
        void Set_major(string i_major);

        int Get_ent_year();
        string Get_major();
};

#endif
```

StudentList.h

```
 #ifndef STUDENTLIST_H_
    #define STUDENTLIST_H_

    #include "Student.h"

    class StudentList {
        private:
            Student *head, *tail;

        public:
            Student p;
            Student *next;
            StudentList ();

            void SList_Init ();
            void AddTail (Student *p);
            void SubString (string s);
            void ListShow ();
            void ReadFile ();
            void findID();
            void findName();
            void findDOB();
            void findAddr();
            void findMajor();
            void findEY();
            void changeName();
            void changeDOB();
            void changeAddr();
            void changeMajor();
            void changeEY();
            void Add_Student ();

            bool is_duplicate(Student t);
    };

    void Open_file (string file_name);
    void Close_file ();

    #endif
```

.cpp file

```
bool equalStudent(Student s1, Student s2) 
{
    return (s1.Get_ent_year() == s2.Get_ent_year())
            && ((s1.Get_addr()).compare(s2.Get_addr()) == 0)
            && ((s1.Get_dob()).compare(s2.Get_dob()) == 0)
            && ((s1.Get_fname()).compare(s2.Get_fname()) == 0)
            && ((s1.Get_major()).compare(s2.Get_major()) == 0);
}


bool is_duplicate(Student s1) {
    Student *head;
    Student *h1 = head;
    while (h1 != NULL) {
        if (equalStudent(h1->p, s1)) {
            return true;
        }
        h1 = h1->next;
    }
    return false;
}

void StudentList:: Add_Student () 
{
    int new_pid, new_ent_year;
    string new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_major;
    cout << endl << "Enter student information:" << endl;
    cout << "Full name: "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin,new_fname);
    cout << "Date of birth: "; getline (cin,new_dob);
    cout << "Address: "; getline (cin,new_addr);
    cout << "Entrance year: "; cin >> new_ent_year;
    cout << "Major: "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin,new_major);

bool duplicate = is_duplicate(new_pid, new_ent_year, new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_major); // call function to check for duplicate info
if (duplicate) {
    string proceed;
    cout << "Duplicated! Continue?  Proceed? [y/n] "; cin.ignore(1); getline (cin, proceed);
    if (proceed != "y") {
        return;
    }
}
Student *p = new Student (new_pid, new_fname, new_dob, new_addr, new_ent_year, new_major);
AddTail (p);

f.seekg(0, ios::end);
f << endl << new_pid << ":" << new_fname << ":" << new_dob << ":" << new_addr << ":" << new_ent_year << ":" << new_major;

}
```

Here's the whole error message:

```
In function 'bool is_duplicate(Student)':
[Error] 'class Student' has no member named 'p'
In member function 'void StudentList::Add_Student()':
[Error] no matching function for call to 'StudentList::is_duplicate(int&, int&, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&, std::string&)'
[Note] candidate is:
In file included from StudentList.cpp
[Note] bool StudentList::is_duplicate(Student)
[Note] candidate expects 1 argument, 6 provided
```

Comment: And would you show us the `Student` class, since the error is about it?

Comment: From what you've shown, the `Student` class doesn't have a member named `p`. What line is generating the error?

Comment: Well, it indeed doesn't have any `p` member. The `p` is in the `StudentList`, not `Student`. Shouldn't it be `equalStudent(*h1, s1)` instead of `equalStudent(h1->p, s1)`?

Comment: Please try removing `Student *head;` in `is_duplicate` function and change `h1->p` into `*h1`

Comment: Instead of creating a data structure useful only for students, create a general data structure (or use `std::list`), and use/create search algorithms (like `std::find_if`) which take the field to search for (either using a functor or lambda expression). This makes the code more modular and expandable.

Comment: @NeilKirk, while you have a point, it is also useful to try implement the most basic data structures yourself for the sake of learning. Also, this might be a homework or assignment.

Comment: I haved tried that and it said "head is not declared in this scope", I thought I declared it already.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall However you shouldn't be creating things and given the false indication that it is "good" or "ok".  Even the design the OP has is strange -- why is `next` a public member of `Student`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your `is_duplicate` to

```
bool StudentList::is_duplicate(Student s1) { //this is a class member function, hence the StudentList::
    Student *h1 = head; //starting with the head of the list, just 1 variable is enough to iterate
    while (h1 != NULL) {
        //comparing current student with s1
        if (equalStudent(*h1, s1)) {
            return true;
        }
        h1 = h1->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also pay attention to your function definitions. While your `Add_Student` is defined right (`void StudentList::Add_Student()`), the rest of the functions are missing the `StudentList::` part, which makes them just global functions, not member functions.

Comment: I actually haved tried that, it said "head is not declared in this scope", I thought I declared it already.

Comment: @Marco, that's because your `is_duplicate` was just a global function. To provide a definition of a function that is a part of the class, it should look like `return_type ClassName::functionName(<...>){<...>}`. You should fix the other functions this way too.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private:
        Student *head, *tail;

    public:
        Student p;
```

your 'p' is an object of type Student in your StudentList class.
What you are saying in you code is to get the object 'p' from Student and not StudentList.

On top of that, Im not completely sure but I think you want 'p' to be a pointer which you define in your cpp later

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_duplicate(Student s1) {
    Student *head;
    Student *h1 = head;
    while (h1 != NULL) {
        if (equalStudent(h1->p, s1)) {
            return true;
        }
        h1 = h1->next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Problem: by declaring a duplicate `Student *head;` in the scope of the method your `Student *h1 = head;` is going to initialize h1 to the uninitialized local variable, not the class member.